# C# equivalent of the Java SecretKeySpec for AES

Tags: java, c#, aes, secret-key

I have following code written in java. I need C# equivalent for this.

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
c.init(1, key);
byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am not familier with C# and it's libraries for AES. I am working on this as If I can find any solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here C# code equivalent in java.

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
AesManaged tdes = new AesManaged();
tdes.Key = UTF8.GetBytes(keyValue);
tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
ICryptoTransform crypt = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] plain = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
byte[] cipher = crypt.TransformFinalBlock(plain, 0, plain.Length);
String encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipher);
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am tying to do the same.Thanks.

Comment: please provide me Java Equivalent to C#  new SecretKeySpec(decodeSecretKey, 0, decodeSecretKey.Length, "AES").getEncoded();

Comment: I would add: if (keyValue.Length > 16) KeyValue=KeyValue.substring(0,16), because if Keyvalue is > 16 length, then will crash on UTF8.GetBytes