# Converting Android Studio (Java) to C#.NET

Tags: c#, android

How can I convert Android Studio (Java) into C#.NET.
I am trying to decrypt a file using C#.NET

```
static void decrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/encrypted");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/decrypted");
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
        fos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    cis.close();
}
```

Here what I've initially done. I can't figure out what was the equivalent of SecretKeySpecs in C#.NET

```
private void FileDecrypt()
        {
            FileStream fis = new FileStream("data/encrypted", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            FileStream fos = new FileStream("data/decrypted", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            
            // Some code in here.
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103680/14584408)?

Comment: It only encrypt a certain string, I'm about decrypt a file particularly a decrypted database for security.